# Don't submit form if inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I have two sets of data: "heat" and "cold", which are retrieved from another provider. This data is quite unorganized and I have removed lots of stuff in the code just to show the essential part of my problem. "Heat" and "cold" both contain properties that the user has to fill in. This property however is dynamic and the amount of properties is not fixed (hence it is in a loop as shown in the code).

My goal is to hide/disable the submit button, which is located all the way down, whenever one single input field in the list in either sets of data is empty. This should also preferably work on Internet Explorer 9, where the 'required' tag is not supported.

I have tried:

- Adding the required tag. This unfortunately does not work in IE9 and I have some issues even in Google Chrome because it is still submitting my form. (I added the form tags too)
- Adding Ng-show on the submit form. I checked whether the userInput is empty, but this still does not work.
- Now you may ask, why wouldn't I just check in my controller whether these properties are empty in my submit method? While it is a good point, I can not access this dynamic data very easily in my controller. Hence, I need a solution that will hopefully fix this problem with no/mimimal effort in the controller.

Code:

```
<!--Start wrapper!-->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div ng-repeat="(code, program) in data.old.heat">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(componentId, component) in program">  
      <div class="inputForm">
        <!--This field may not be left empty!-->
        <input type="text" class="form" ng-model="component.userInput">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="(code, program) in data.old.cold">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="(componentId, component) in program">
      <div class="inputForm">
        <!--This field may not be left empty!-->
        <input type="text" class="form" ng-model="component.userInput">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
<!--End of wrapper !-->

<div class="submitPanel">
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add a hidden field outside these forms, with a little code that populates it with "Yes, they did something", from either form.  Just check the condition of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two options for you, but they both include `ng-disabled` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).

You can put this attribute on the button and you can either call a function on the scope in that attribute and check if all values are given.

So like: `ng-disabled="checkInputs()"`.

Or

You wrap a form around all your inputs, give the form a name like `name=form` and set the `required` attribute on all inputs. (**EDIT**: you could use `ng-required="true"` for IE9.)

Then you could say `ng-disabled="!form.$valid"`.

Comment: Thank you! Will try this as well! Will get back asap!

Comment: My only concern is that I can not use this due problems with checking if the values are given, since I can not easily get these values from my controller in the ''checkInputs()'' method

Comment: And how about the second approach?

Comment: Wauw, totally missed that one! Will definitely try this out tomorrow early morning! I really appreciate your advice! Especially if it is working with IE9

Comment: I will try this tomorrow morning in my app, but I have tried it for now @ Fiddle and it did not unfortunately work here. Did I miss something? http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17875/

Comment: I edited it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17876/, you were supposed to use `ng-required="true"`.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try and get back tomorrow!

Comment: Cleanest, neatest and best working method. Thank you Pepijn!

Comment: That is indeed the best way to go (the second approach). Also node that angular automatically takes nested forms into consideration when setting the $valid/$invalid flag, hence if you have nested forms, each form will be set according to its fields and the status of nested forms.

Comment: And one more things, instead of:
ng-disabled="!form.$valid" you could use the invalid value:
ng-disabled="form.$invalid"

Answer (score 4):

Here ya go : https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/zxbe5rt0/

```
function validate(){
var text1 = document.getElementById('text').value;

if (text1.length > 0){
    alert("went through");
    return true;
}
alert("did not go through");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Interesting thank you! Will try this out asap and will come back to this.

Comment: Doesn't really look like a very clean angular approach.

Comment: @Pepijn and why exactly does it need to be angular?

Comment: Angular gives you a lot of tools to do this easily and maintainable. You don't want to a document search on the entire page if you have a big page and maybe have the risk of having inputs with the same ID. I would say doing this with angular is less risky than doing it this way.

Comment: Also it's plainly bad practice.

Comment: @Pepijn you show me where it says its bad practice, lol. Sure, there are times you should not do this, however in this circumstance it will be just fine.

Comment: If you have scope defined and start looking for the data outside of that scope, I would say that's a bad practice.

Comment: @Pepijn your a funny guy!

Answer (score 4):

Not specific to angular, but you could check if it has characters via `jQuery`.

Html

```
<div class="submitPanel">
  <button class="submit-btn" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#form input').blur(function()
{
    if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
        $(this).parents('.submit-btn').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try this early morning and get back! But I assume I still need to wrap my code with the form tags? (since you are saying #form)

Comment: Check comments under other question, voting against this kind of approach!

Comment: I was just using it because I have a similar project that needed the same thing. However, it's semantically correct to wrap a form in a `<form>` tag. You could just give the input you want hidden a class or id and say `$('#idname').blur(function() {`  or `$('.classname').blur(function() {`

Comment: @Pepijn We all do things differently. I personally would rather handle small things like this in jquery as opposed to angular. So that's why I provided a jquery solution. No need to downvote someone because it doesn't follow the way you do something.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, why use 2 frameworks next to each other if one could use one?

Comment: @Pepijn oops, my mistake, when you said "voting against" I thought you meant you were down voting all the jquery solutions.

This is just me, but I never had an angular project that didn't also utilize jQuery at some point, I'm assuming that he could be using both.

Comment: That's true, I mostly try to go for only angular jqLite, because my Junior devs usually try to hack stuff into something with jQuery and that's not maintable at enterprise scale.

Comment: @ether pepijn is just trolling for non-angular answers lol, his understanding of "scope" is a little off, however like my answer, your answer is good too! Its funny to see people that are so stuck in their way they will go out of their way to down play someone's approach. there are 1,000 good ways to skin a cat, pick one :)

Comment: I figure if it doesn't help this guy, it will help someone else down the road. haha

Comment: hehe, some burning @AdamBuchananSmith, I was talking about document scope vs. controller scope. You were definitely searching in two different scopes.

Comment: @ether you are correct! I up-voted your answer, keep it up.